# Passing props in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this component:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: solved === true ? 'green' : '#ff5b68'}}>
    <Text>{error}</Text>
    <Text>{errorInfo}</Text>
    <Text>{key}</Text>
    <Text>{uid}</Text>
    <MarkedAsSolvedButton key={key}/>
</View>
```

And I want to pass the key to the `MarkedAsSolvedButton` component. Code below:

```
export default class MarkedAsSolvedButton extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        alert(nextProps.key)
    }

    handlePress = () => {
        alert(this.props.key);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Button onPress={this.handlePress} title={'Marked as solved' + this.props.key}/>
        );
    }
}
```

But when I try to see the key, it says `undefined`. But it gives me the value in the parent component.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`key` is a very special prop in react, and it is deliberately **not** exposed to the child component. It exists as a way to provide react with additional information that it can use to optimize performance, especially when dealing with lists (see [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)). If you need the information to be exposed to the child, you'll need to pass it as a different prop (this could either be in addition to a key prop, or instead of it). For example:

```
// In the parent component's render:

<MarkAsSolvedButton key={key} identifier={key} />

// in MarkAsSolved:
handlePress = () => {
  alert(this.props.identifier);
}
```

Comment: You can see the full list [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
onPressButton(){}
render() {
    return (
     <ChildrenComponent
      name={"testing to props"}
      onFunction={this.onPressButton.bind(this)}
      key={this.state.key}
    />
    );
}
```

and in children component

```
<View>
    <Button onPress={()=>this.props.onFunction(this.props.key)}>
      <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
    </Button>
</View>
```

you can use like that with difrent props after render you can call props

Answer (score -1):

Add constructor with props:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)           
}
```